# Poll a webservice using Reactive Extensions and bind the last x results

Tags: c#, system.reactive

I'm trying to use Reactive Extensions (Rx) for a task where it seems to be a good fit, polling at a specific interval a web service and display its last x results.

I have a web service that sends me the status of an instrument I want to monitor. I would like to poll this instrument at a specific rate and display in a list the last 20 status that have been polled.

So my list would be like a "moving window" of the service result.

I'm developing a WPF app with Caliburn.Micro, but I don't think this is very relevant.

What I managed to get until now is the following (just a sample app that I hacked quickly, I'm not going to do this in the ShellViewModel in the real app):

```
public class ShellViewModel : Caliburn.Micro.PropertyChangedBase, IShell
{
    private ObservableCollection<string> times;
    private string currentTime;

    public ShellViewModel()
    {
        times = new ObservableCollection<string>();

        Observable
            .Interval(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1))
            .SelectMany(x => this.GetCurrentDate().ToObservable())
            .ObserveOnDispatcher()
            .Subscribe(x =>
            {
                this.CurrentTime = x;
                this.times.Add(x);
            });
    }

    public IEnumerable<string> Times
    {
        get
        {
            return this.times;
        }
    }

    public string CurrentTime
    {
        get
        {
            return this.currentTime;
        }
        set
        {
            this.currentTime = value;
            this.NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => this.CurrentTime);
        }
    }

    private async Task<string> GetCurrentDate()
    {
        var client = new RestClient("http://www.timeapi.org");
        var request = new RestRequest("/utc/now.json");

        var response = await client.ExecuteGetTaskAsync(request);

        return response.Content;
    }
}
```

In the view I have just a label bound to the `CurrentTime` property and a list bound to the `Times` property.

The issue I have is:

- It's not limited to the 20 items in the list as I always add items to the `ObservableCollection` but I can't find a better way to databind
- The Interval doesn't work as I'd like. If the querying takes more than 1 second to run, two queries will be run in parallel, which I'd like not to happen. My goal would be that the query repeats indefinitely but at a pace of no more than 1 query every seconds. If a query makes more than 1 second to end, it should wait for it to have finish and directly trigger the new query.

Second edit:

Previous edit below was me being stupid and very confused, it triggers events continuously because Interval is something continuous that never ends. Brandon's solution is correct and works as expected.

Edit:

Based on Brandon's example, I tried to do the following code in LinqPad:

```
Observable
    .Merge(Observable.Interval(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2)), Observable.Interval(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10)))
    .Repeat()
    .Scan(new List<double>(), (list, item) => { list.Add(item); return list; })
    .Subscribe(x => Console.Out.WriteLine(x))
```

And I can see that the write to the console occurs every 2 seconds, and not every 10. So the Repeat doesn't wait for both Observable to be finished before repeating.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this:

```
// timer that completes after 1 second
var intervalTimer = Observable
    .Empty<string>()
    .Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));

// queries one time whenever subscribed
var query = Observable.FromAsync(GetCurrentDate);

// query + interval timer which completes
// only after both the query and the timer
// have expired

var intervalQuery = Observable.Merge(query, intervalTimer);

// Re-issue the query whenever intervalQuery completes
var queryLoop = intervalQuery.Repeat();

// Keep the 20 most recent results
// Note.  Use an immutable list for this
// https://www.nuget.org/packages/microsoft.bcl.immutable
// otherwise you will have problems with
// the list changing while an observer
// is still observing it.
var recentResults = queryLoop.Scan(
    ImmutableList.Create<string>(), // starts off empty
    (acc, item) =>
    {
        acc = acc.Add(item);
        if (acc.Count > 20)
        {
            acc = acc.RemoveAt(0);
        }

        return acc;
    });

// store the results
recentResults
    .ObserveOnDispatcher()
    .Subscribe(items =>
    {
        this.CurrentTime = items[0];
        this.RecentItems = items;
    });
```

Comment: Very interesting answer, thanks. So I see there is no real other way to get the list of items returned by the query than to scan the query and create a list.
Is there a reason why you didn't use [TakeLast](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh212114(v=vs.103).aspx) and did the check in the scan for the 20 items?
Also, what if I want to be able to dynamically change the 1s delay between polling?

Comment: `TakeLast` takes the **last** N items from the stream, not the **most recent** N items.  In other words it will produce nothing at all until the stream *completes*, then it will yield the last N items it produced.  Not very useful here.  If you wrap the definition of `intervalTimer` with `Observable.Defer` and also make it read a variable or call a function for the timespan, then `Defer` will rebuild the timer on each iteration, giving you your opportunity to change the delay period.

Comment: Ah, so that's why my tests with Take and TakeLast weren't successful. Thanks again for your help.

Comment: Ouch, after a few tests, it doesn't seem to work correctly.
The merge doesn't work like that, it doesn't wait for both to be completed, it just merges to events of both Observable.

Comment: yeah that is how `Merge` works.  But it won't *complete* (and thus won't trigger the `Repeat`) until both complete.  Post your updated code.

Comment: See my edit with a similar code where you can see that the `Repeat` doesn't wait for both to be finished before repeating. I'm very confused...

Comment: That is because `Interval` keeps producing values every period and never completes.  Your code doesn't match my answer.  For simplicities sake, change your `Interval` to `Timer` (which only fires once then completes) and it will work as described.

Comment: Yes, you're right, sorry I was being dumb. There was another issue that made me think that it didn't work as expected. Now I've found what was the issue and your code works as expected. Thanks a lot and sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 0):

This should skip the interval messages while a GetCurrentDate is in Progress.

```
Observable
    .Interval(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1))
    .GroupByUntil(p => 1,p => GetCurrentDate().ToObservable().Do(x => {
                            this.CurrentTime = x;
                            this.times.Add(x);
                        }))
    .SelectMany(p => p.LastAsync())
    .Subscribe();
```